# Oracle database changes to some MQ client

Tags: oracle11g, apache-kafka, oracle-aq, oracle-golden-gate, oracle-streams

Hi Oracle DB guys out there, Is there a way to propagate DML changes in database to some MQ server(Kafka in my case). I have read about following but coulnt find any concrete implementation

oracle streams:- which are for database to database replication

oracle strams AQ:- for integration with MQ clients

GoldenGate: which we cannot use because of cost